# Android Camera Take Picture Add Crop Video

Tags: android, camera, crop

Requirement of the Application is that Android when we have media picker with take picture option.

While i take the picture, i want to add the Crop picture window after picture is taken.

Issues: Few OEM have their own Crop picture functionality already implemented. So if we add one more Crop window which would result in 2 crop windows, not advisable.

How can i achieve that functionality which can tell me No Crop window is there so can add my own crop window and where its there i can go further without effect.

Thanks in Advance!!